# How can i set zIndex for Scrollview?

Tags: javascript, scrollview, famo.us

I have stack of ScrollViews which has a list of surfaces within it.

I need to stack the scrollviews properly. But for stacking surfaces im able to do it by zIndex property ?

But im not able to set zIndex property for ScrollView ?

this works

```
    this.surface.setProperties({
        zIndex: index
    });
```

this doesn't

```
    this.scrollview.setProperties({
        zIndex: index
    });
```

Whats an equivalent function to set zIndex for scrollview.

Thanks.

Comment: i used a containersurface to set the zindex .. it worked ..

    this.scrollContainer = new ContainerSurface({
        size:[undefined,undefined],
        properties: { overflow: 'hidden', 'z-index': 5 }
    });
    this.scrollContainer.add(this.scrollview);

Answer (score 0):

i used a containersurface to set the zindex .. it worked ..

```
this.scrollContainer = new ContainerSurface({
    size:[undefined,undefined],
    properties: { overflow: 'hidden', 'z-index': 5 }
});
this.scrollContainer.add(this.scrollview);
```

containerSurface we can set properties ..